# how can I execute a script shell with node.js

Tags: node.js, shell, child-process

I am trying to execute a script shell with node.js .I am Using a child process but when I execute the .js file the script shell is not bee executed . What's wrong with this function?

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec('/home/nadhem/TradeFinance/Backend/SmartContract/approveLOC.sh', 
(err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }

  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Comment: Can you post the actual error it's throwing?

Comment: Alternatively you can check out `shelljs` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/shelljs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of documentation for execution file you should use:

`child_process.execFile(file[, args][, options][, callback])`

This would work for you.

```
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
execFile('/home/nadhem/TradeFinance/Backend/SmartContract/approveLOC.sh', 
(err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    return;
  }

  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```